# In Orphan Black, who shot the woman, and who saved her?

Tags: character-motivation, orphan-black

At the end of season 3, in a parking garage, someone shoots

> Delphine Cormier.

Who was it? Was it at the instigation of

> Evie Cho?

And who saved her, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Delphine Cormier. was shot by Detective Martin Duko for Evie Cho, as Evie had no interest in clones and her faction had different agenda. But she was saved by Dr. Ian Van Lier.

This all was witnessed by Krystal Goderitch and revelaed in S04E10.